# Oracle Apex 19 Web Source Module: Get list inside returning JSON object

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm working with Oracle APEX 19 and using the Web Source Module to get data from https://swapi.co/api/people/. However, I haven't been able to find a way to map/get the data displayed on datatypes that are lists, like the films and starships properties.

I maps the other properties (eg.: name, height, mass, etc.) fine and I get that a list wouldn't be a valid datattype for a column, I was thinking more in the lines of it becoming a new table or a way to connect different object to do a master detail screen.

I'm rather new with the tool and I haven't been able to find a way or a tutorial to teach me how to do it using APEX. Is it at all possible through only APEX? Should I try to do it with PL/SQL instead?

Thx in advance

Comment: Hi Paulo, did you still need help with this? I don't know of a declarative option in APEX, but as you hinted, you could do something with PL/SQL. If you want help with this, please provide more detail about what you'd like to see.

Comment: @Paulo Künzel, did you find the solution? I have problems with the same issue.

Comment: Hi Tito, I've made a few find/replace that I'm not proud of.. So yes, I need help.. lol